# Problems installing BurpKit - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jfxpanel

When I install the extension in Burp Suite, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at burp.sue.a(Unknown Source)
    at burp.sue.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at burp.mn.a(Unknown Source)
    at burp.ooh.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux, for example Ubuntu, you should install openjfx  from terminal. Then reboot and it should work

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```